# Find $( \dotsb ((2017 \diamond 2016) \diamond 2015) \diamond \dotsb \diamond 2) \diamond 1$ given ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For positive real numbers $a$ and $b,$ let
>   $$a \diamond b = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 4ab + b^2 - 2a - 2b + 9}}{ab + 6}.$$Find
>   $$( \dotsb ((2017 \diamond 2016) \diamond 2015) \diamond \dotsb \diamond 2) \diamond 1.$$

---

I can't find any quick way to do this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing other than more parentheses in that leading ellipsis, right?

Comment: yes, there are only the opening parentheses of all the \*functions\*

Comment: Similar to my question PSE: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/the-numbers-on-blackboard

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Notice for all positive number $a$, we have

$$a \diamond 2 = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 8a + 4 - 2a - 4 + 9}}{2a+6} = \frac{\sqrt{a^2+6a+9}}{2a+6} = \frac12$$

The mess at hand equals to
$$( (\cdots) \diamond 2) \diamond 1 = \frac12 \diamond 1 = \frac{\sqrt{37}}{13}$$

Comment: does it follow from the fact the $((a \diamond b) \diamond c) = (a \diamond (b \diamond c))$?

Comment: @Alex, nope. The first thing I do is check whether the $\diamond$ operation is associative and it isn't.

Comment: In your calculation, $a \diamond 2$, what is $a$? All terms between 2017 and 3 or 3?

Comment: @Alex $a$ can be any positive number. if you substitute it by all the terms between 2017 and 3, you get the mess between 2017 and 2.

Comment: OK, so in you construct $a=(\ldots)$, i.e. $\diamond$ between all terms between 3 and 2017. Is it guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: I tried solving for $a \diamond (a-1)$, didn't get anything useful

Comment: Since $a^2 + 4ab + b^2 - 2(a+b) + 9 = (a+b - 1)^2 + 2ab + 8$. If you start from any $a, b > 0$, this will be $> 8$, so $a \circ b$ is positive. Repeat applying this, one can deduce all terms between 2017 and 3 is positive.

Comment: OK I think I got it, so essentially $a=(\ldots)$